# What does range or map return?

Tags: dictionary, go, range

Go has very neat multiple return values paradigm. But It looks like `v, ok := map[key]` and `v, k := range m` use different mechanism with same notation. Here is a simple example:

```
func f2() (k, v string) {
    return "Hello", "World"
}

func main(){
    k := f2() // Doesn't work : multiple-value f2() in single-value context

    m := map[string]int{"One": 1}

    // It works
    v, ok := m["One"]

    // How it all work?
    v := m["One"]
    for k := range m {}
}
```

In above example, `k := f2()` gives error as `f2` returns two values, whereas `v, ok := m["One"]` and `v := m["One"]` - both expressions work without any error.
Why is that different behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fetch from the built in `map`, using `range` on a map, array or slice, and also `type assertions` allows for one *or* two variables. This is not the case for user defined functions and methods. If a function declares two return values, you must tell what to do with both of them, or ignore both:

```
k, _ := f2() // Specify what to do with each returned value
f2() // Ignoring both
```

Why? Because the specification says it is so:

**[Map (indexed expressions):](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)**

> An index expression on a map a of type map[K]V may be used in an assignment or initialization of the special form
>
> v, ok = a[x]
>   v, ok := a[x]
>   var v, ok = a[x]
>
> where the result of the index expression is a pair of values with types (V, bool). In this form, the value of ok is true if the key x is present in the map, and false otherwise. The value of v is the value a[x] as in the single-result form.

**[Range (for statement):](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)**

> For each iteration, iteration values are produced as follows:
>
> Range expression: m map[K]V
>   1st value:        key k K
>   2nd value (if 2nd variable is present): m[k] V

**[Type assertion:](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)**

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary expression
>   x.(T)
>   asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.

and

> If a type assertion is used in an assignment or initialization of the form
>   v, ok = x.(T)
>   v, ok := x.(T)
>   var v, ok = x.(T)
>   the result of the assertion is a pair of values with types (T, bool)