# Why map and type assertion can return 1 or 2 values?

Tags: go, type-assertion

To define a map, we can do such a thing:

`value, present := m["key"]`

or:

`value := m["key"]`

and with type assertion, we can do:

```
var i interface{} = "hello"

s := i.(string)
fmt.Println(s)

s, ok := i.(string)
fmt.Println(s, ok)
```

but I can't find a way to define a func that can return 1 value or 2-values.

For instance:

```
func hello() (string, error) {
    return "world", nil
}
```

When I invoke this func I get:

```
v, ok := hello() // valid
v := hello() // invalid
```

PS: I know how something like `template.Must` works, but it seems different. I really want to know how Map and type assertion can do the magic, so I can apply it to functions.

Thanks in advance. (Am I clear? I have poor English sorry).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go: What does range or map return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741174/go-what-does-range-or-map-return)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Function types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types)
>
> A function type denotes the set of all functions with the same
>   parameter and result types.
>
> ```
> FunctionType   = "func" Signature .
> Signature      = Parameters [ Result ] .
> Result         = Parameters | Type .
> Parameters     = "(" [ ParameterList [ "," ] ] ")" .
> ParameterList  = ParameterDecl { "," ParameterDecl } .
> ParameterDecl  = [ IdentifierList ] [ "..." ] Type .
> ```
>
> [Blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier)
>
> The blank identifier is represented by the underscore character _.
>
> [Assignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments)
>
> The blank identifier provides a way to ignore right-hand side values
>   in an assignment:
>
> ```
> x, _ = f()  // evaluate f() but ignore second result value
> ```

Maps, type assertions, and the `for` statement with a `range` clause are special features of the Go programming language. You can't have a variable number of return values for an ordinary function type.

You can ignore a return value with an underscore (_), the blank identifier,  or you can use a wrapper function. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func two() (int, bool) {
    return 42, true
}

func one() int {
    r, _ := two()
    return r
}

func main() {
    r, ok := two()
    r, _ = two()
    r = one()
    fmt.Println(r, ok)
}
```

Comment: "Maps, type assertions, and the for statement with a range clause are special features of the Go programming language." Is it in the spec?

Answer (score 7):

Map and type assertions can do this because they are not functions, but structures of the language. The behavior is described in the spec

> An index expression on a map a of type map[K]V used in an assignment
>   or initialization of the special form
>
> ```
> v, ok = a[x]
> v, ok := a[x]
> var v, ok = a[x]
> ```
>
> yields an additional untyped boolean value. The value of ok is true if
>   the key x is present in the map, and false otherwise.

and

> A type assertion used in an assignment or initialization of the
>   special form
>
> ```
> v, ok = x.(T)
> v, ok := x.(T)
> var v, ok = x.(T)
> ```
>
> yields an additional untyped boolean value. The value of ok is true if
>   the assertion holds. Otherwise it is false and the value of v is the
>   zero value for type T. No run-time panic occurs in this case.

It is not something that can be done on general functions, hence the `Must` pattern that explicitely reproduce the same behavior.